# How can I change colors of segments in trace?

Tags: r, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I try to change colors of trace using a sunburst chart in R plot-ly.

I put an example.

```
data1 <- data.frame(
ids=c("up","down","noCh","up-win","down-win","up-loss","down-loss",   "noCh-win","noCh-loss"),
labels= c("up","down","noCh","win","loss","win","loss","win","loss"),
parents=c("","","","up","up","down","down","noCh","noCh" ),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- plot_ly() %>%
 add_trace(
   ids = data1$ids,
   labels = data1$labels,
   parents =data1$parents,
   type = 'sunburst',
   maxdepth = 3,
   domain = list(column = 1)
 )%>% 
 layout(
 grid = list(columns =1, rows = 1),
 margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0),
 colorway=c("orange","yellow","green")
 )
```

I got the plot like this:

[image]

I try to change colors of the outside part ("win", "loss"). The win is red color and loss is a blue color. How can I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do it, is to add another column to your data.frame in which you specify the desired color for the segment and pass the variable to your trace:

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  ids=c("up","down","noCh","up-win","down-win","up-loss","down-loss",   "noCh-win","noCh-loss"),
  labels= c("up","down","noCh","win","loss","win","loss","win","loss"),
  parents=c("","","","up","up","down","down","noCh","noCh" ),
  col = c("orange","yellow","green", rep(c("red", "blue"), 3)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    ids = data1$ids,
    labels = data1$labels,
    parents =data1$parents,
    type = 'sunburst',
    maxdepth = 3,
    marker = list(colors = data1$col),
    domain = list(column = 1)
  )%>% 
  layout(
    grid = list(columns =1, rows = 1),
    margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0)
  )

p
```

[image]