# Nest donut chart with plotly or highcharts in R

Tags: r, highcharts, plotly, donut-chart

```
library(webr)
data <- as.data.frame(Titanic)  

pd = data %>% 
  group_by(Class, Survived) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(Freq))

PieDonut(pd,  aes(Class, Survived, count = n),
         labelposition = 0,
         r0 = 0.5,
         r1 = 0.95,
         title = "Titanic: Survial by Class")
```

This donut fig was made With `webr` package, is it possible to polt such an interactive fig with `plotly` or `highchart`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### 1. The `plotly` way

The input data format for `plotly`'s sunburst option is confusing (i.e. a bit of a pain); the relevant example in the documentation is [Sunburst with Repeated Labels](https://plotly.com/r/sunburst-charts/#sunburst-with-repeated-labels).

The key is to

1. transform the data in the following way by adding marginal sums (both total and group-level, see my in-line comments), and
2. add a unique `ids` column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- bind_rows(
    # Full total
    pd %>% summarise(labels = "Total", n = sum(n)),
    # "Class"-level totals
    pd %>% 
        group_by(labels = Class) %>% 
        summarise(
            n = sum(n), 
            parents = "Total",
            .groups = "drop"),
    # Individual Class+Survived-level numbers
    pd %>% 
        rename(parents = Class, labels = Survived) %>%
        mutate(parents = paste("Total", parents, sep = " - "))) %>%
    # Add unique ids column
    mutate(ids = if_else(
        is.na(parents), labels, paste(parents, labels, sep = " - ")))
## A tibble: 13 × 4
#   labels     n parents      ids               
#   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>             
# 1 Total   2201 NA           Total             
# 2 1st      325 Total        Total - 1st       
# 3 2nd      285 Total        Total - 2nd       
# 4 3rd      706 Total        Total - 3rd       
# 5 Crew     885 Total        Total - Crew      
# 6 No       122 Total - 1st  Total - 1st - No  
# 7 Yes      203 Total - 1st  Total - 1st - Yes 
# 8 No       167 Total - 2nd  Total - 2nd - No  
# 9 Yes      118 Total - 2nd  Total - 2nd - Yes 
#10 No       528 Total - 3rd  Total - 3rd - No  
#11 Yes      178 Total - 3rd  Total - 3rd - Yes 
#12 No       673 Total - Crew Total - Crew - No 
#13 Yes      212 Total - Crew Total - Crew - Yes
```

Then

```r
library(plotly)
plot_ly(
    data = df,
    ids = ~ids,
    labels = ~labels,
    parents = ~parents,
    values = ~n,
    type = "sunburst",
    branchvalues = "total")
```

[image]

---

### 2. The `highcharter` way

`highcharter` provides the convenience function `data_to_hierarchical()` to reformat input data for a sunburst visualisation:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
pd %>% 
    data_to_hierarchical(c(Class, Survived), n) %>%
    hchart(type = "sunburst")
```

[image]

Comment: Hero!!, How to fill the `Survived` with 2 colors, one is as the same as the `Class`, another with alpha =0.6.

Comment: @LeeJim For the `plotly` solution, this is explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064828/how-can-i-change-colors-of-segments-in-trace).

Comment: Yes! this meet my need.